# Replacing past perfect tense with past tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, tenses, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

For *had fallen* in a when-clause, can the past perfect tense be replaced with the past tense?

> Easily the most boring class was History of Magic, which was the only
>   one taught by a ghost. Professor Binns **had been** very old indeed
>   when he **had fallen** asleep in front of the staffroom fire and **got
>   up** next morning to teach, leaving his body behind him. Binns droned
>   on and on while they scribbled down names and dates, and got Emetic
>   the Evil and Uric the Oddball mixed up.

Comment: Can it be replaced and be grammatical? ... and mean the same thing? ... and be as easy for the reader to understand what is happening?  If you're worried about the tenses in that sentence not matching, I consider there to be an elided **had** in front of **got up**. So in American English, it would be **gotten up**.

Comment: Yes - it's imprecise _with_ the elision, and unwieldy if you put the _had_ in.

Comment: I don't think it's imprecise at all with the elision. I would say that if you want to take the second verb out of past perfect, you need to put in another **he** before **got up**. This also throws the relative timing of the passage askew in a way that putting **had fallen** into the simple past would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace **had fallen** with **fell** in the sentence, it is certainly grammatical, and it means essentially the same thing. Rowling has put the whole sentence in into the past perfect to emphasize that this happened a long time before the class that Binns is currently teaching. It may look at first sight as if the last verb (**got**) is not in past perfect, but in fact it is. There is an elided **had** before the **got** (more specifically, the **had** before the **fallen** also modifies the **got**).